# Unable to connect to Broadband/PPPOE connection in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: networking, 16.04, pppoe, dsl

I have a newly installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS in my computer and I am unable to set up a DSL connection. The same connection works when I use it in Windows 8.1 but does not work in Ubuntu. I did set up the connection using the terminal with `pppoeconf` but after finishing the process, I was again unable to use the connection. When i try the `pon` command, it gives me the following error/message:

```
/usr/sbin/pppd: In file etc/ppp/peers/provider: unrecognized option '/dev/modem'
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually I was trying to run my connection with the `sudo pon` command. The correct way is to type `sudo pon dns-provider`.

Comment: Did this resolved your problem?